# How to type the three dots in a product?

Tags: math-mode, symbols

I have to type the product of n variables, `$x_1\cdot\ldots\cdot x_n$`. 
Although maybe this is semantically the right way (like it is for the sum), it doesn't look very well. What should be, typographically, a better way to do it?

For example:

Just the ldots as in `$x_1\ldots x_n$` is confusing when there are going to be also lists of the variables separated by commas in nearby sentences.

With `\dotsc` like in `$x_1\dotsc x_n$` maybe, but is there a better idea?

Comment: This web site doesn't parse LaTeX? That would be funny!

Comment: It was removed since it interferes with displaying raw LaTeX code (which we need to see more often than we need to see rendered mathematics). See [meta](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Use `\cdots`. (See also: `\vdots` and `\ddots`.)

### Edit

Actually, I just read in the [«Short Math Guide for LaTeX» by the AMS](http://tug.ctan.org/info/short-math-guide/short-math-guide.pdf) that:

- `\dotsc` is for dots with commas,
- `\dotsb` is for dots with binary operators,
- `\dotsm` is for multiplication dots,
- `\dotsi` is for dots with integrals,
- `\dotso` is for other dots.

So, `\cdots` and `\ldots` are commonly used but the AMS convention is to use the more semantic commands.

Comment: So, \dotsm then.

Answer (score 7):

Or you can use `\dots` which can be used both inside and outside of math-mode.

Answer (score 0):

The above link to the «Short Math Guide for LaTeX» by the AMS seems to be broken.
Correct link is: http://tug.ctan.org/info/short-math-guide/short-math-guide.pdf

(As answer as I cannot comment)