# Outputing matrix-vector in latex?

Tags: math-mode, equations

I have to write a formula like this:

[image]

Using:

```
\begin{equation}
\left( \begin{matrix} n \\ k \end{matrix} \right) =\frac { n(n-1)\quad ...\quad (n-k+1) }{ k(k-1)...1 } 
\end{equation}
```

The daum equation editor puts the `n` on top of `k` but in my latex output, I get don't get the same:

[image]

**What should I do to make my the `n` be on top of `k`?** How do I get the same output as the one shown on daum equation editor?

Comment: you haven't used `\usepackage{amsmath}`

Comment: oooo that changes how `\begin{equation}` works. cool, now it works. never knew that. Why is that so?

Comment: @alvas: Because `matrix` is an `amsmath` addition, I would say. And please don't post screenshots of code, this is quite tedious to read and can't be changed

Comment: no it defines the matrix environment

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use `amsmath` as package as one possibility or `\binom{n}{k}` as the quick alternative (requires `amsmath` or `mathtools` however too)

`matrix` is defined by `amsmath`, so this environment needs the `amsmath` package.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\texttt{Bad example -- do not use this}
\begin{equation}
\left( \begin{matrix} n \\ k \end{matrix} \right) =\frac { n(n-1)\quad ...\quad (n-k+1) }{ k(k-1)...1 } 
\end{equation}


\texttt{Good example ;-)}
\begin{equation}
\binom{n}{k} =\frac { n(n-1) \dots (n-k+1) }{ k(k-1)\dots 1 } 
\end{equation}


\end{document}
```

[image]

The second version with `\binom`, `\dots` and **without** `\quad` does indeed look better and provides better spacings. Literal `...` are no good way to provide such ellipsis. Thats what `\dots` is meant for.

Comment: I'd remove the first version altogether.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer -- i think you mean "without `\quad` and *with* `\cdots`".  (looks lots better to me too.  i might be willing to consider the `\quad`, but won't ever accept literal `...` instead of some `\dots` construction.)

Comment: @barbarabeeton: Yes, of course -- I was too quick. I mean `\without`

Comment: @egreg: I'll keep the first 'method' as a bad example and will explicitly state in the post that the second one is better

Comment: Just nitpicking, but I'd prefer `\dots` (which in this case would use low dots, which are normal for denoting implicit terms in a multiplication.

Comment: @egreg: Alright, I can live with `\dots` although `\cdots` look nicer. If you have to nitpick something else, let me know ;-)

Comment: Doesn't `amsmath` have a command `\dotsm` which means exactly "dots in a multiplication", semantically? See [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1176/how-to-type-the-three-dots-in-a-product), for instance.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni: Yes, that's true. I've learned just something. Thanks, I will edit my solution later on and refer to your comment!